# React open Api response in browser window

Tags: reactjs, integration

I am new to React.
I am integrating a payment gateway [Kiple] whose process is as follow:

> Post Api with Params -> A window will open -> Costumer enter credentials -> Response will recieve back to specified url [Same as Paypal integration behaves]

I am doing this:

```
Axios.post("https://uat.kiplepay.com/wcgatewayinit.php", {
        ord_date: "24/11/2020",
        ....    
        
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
    })
   .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

This method though calls API successfully, but returns form html in respose as text. Somehow I want that when this Api hits, Kiple form opens in browser window.

Let me know how to achieve it. I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Is the response a string? if so you can do something like this

```
    const [response, setResponse] = useState('');
        ...

    Axios.post("https://uat.kiplepay.com/wcgatewayinit.php", {
        ord_date: "24/11/2020",
        ....    
        
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setResponse(res.data);
    })
   .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
        ...

  return(
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: response }} />
  )
```